# How variables in Azure Pipelines be used in Container's NodeJS code directly?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, environment-variables, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I tried to set variables in Azure Pipelines' Release which can be used Command Task in Release to replace variables' values to Docker Kubernetes' .yaml file.

It works fine for me but I need to prepare several Command Tasks to replace variables one by one.

For example, I set variable TESTING1_(value:Test1), TESTING2_(value:Test2) and TESTING3_(value:Test3) in Pipelines' Release. Then I only used Command Task to replace TESTING1_ to $(TESTING1_) in Docker Kubernetes' .yaml file. Below is original environment setting in .yaml file:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: devops
      env:
      - name: TESTING1
        value: TESTING1_
      - name: TESTING2
        value: $(TESTING2_)
```

After ran Pipelines' Release, print out results in NodeJS were:

> console.log(process.env.TESTING1); --> Test1
>
> console.log(process.env.TESTING2); --> $(TESTING2_)
>
> console.log(process.env.TESTING3); --> undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should be use config maps for that (maybe update values in config maps). you shouldn't be updating containers directly. this gives you flexibility and management.  example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
      env:
        - name: SPECIAL_LEVEL_KEY
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: special-config
              key: special.how
```

and then if some value changes you update the config map and all the pods that reference this config map get new value.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data

Comment: It is good idea. However, as the files will be uploaded to GitHub, how can I protect the values that not being seen by others? Thanks.

Comment: why do you want to upload secrets /configuration to github?

Comment: My all code and Docker files are pushed to GitHub for storage and I use Docker Pipelines for auto-deployment if there is change for files. 

Do you mean that I only need to set Config Maps once by using Kubectl command (by using local file) which can be used for every time of auto-deployment? 

Thus, seems Config Maps is not encrypted which Docker Secrets is (But I am not using Swarm which cannot use Docker Secrets). Is it safe to store password if using Config Maps that others can using Azure Pipelines for deployment?

Thanks

Comment: yes, you create configmap once and then pods just use it (you dont have to have a pipeline for configmap). secrets are a slightly different thing, but you can use those as well, same principle applies, you update the secret >> all the pods get new value. for sensitive data its best to use secrets (or probably some other alternatives, as by defaults secrets can be decrypted easily)

Comment: Got it, thanks.
As I am using Azure WebApp for Container(with Kubernetes) but not Swarm, it cannot use Docker Secrets to store sensitive information. Thus, Config Maps is not encrypted which has risk to leak of sensitive information. It should be better to use back Azure Pipelines' variables with replacing tasks which is more secure. (although need to have several tasks for replacing variables) Thanks a lot..

Comment: i dont understand, kubernetes got secrets. what does it have to do with swarm?

Comment: oh, yes, there is Kubenetes Secrets to use (as I searched if use Docker Secrets, it requires Swarm) (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) But in the Risks part, there are risks to disclose the password.

Comment: ok, at this point i'm really lost. how are environment variables more secure than kubernetes secrets (since you are using environment variables)

Comment: Sorry that after I testing behaviour of using Pipelines' variables and Kubernetes Secrets, I found out it displayed Pipelines' variables values when I use command "kubectl describe pod xxx" only. But if you have right to login Kubernetes Service, then you can also decode of Kubernetes Secrets. Therefore, to prevent store another secrets file/encode manually, I prefer to use Pipelines variables back with convenient setting. Thanks for your help.

Comment: yeah, just as if you have right permissions on vsts you can get variables from vsts. this is a pretty pointless observation